# Is it possible to define a default variable in a function before It's defined?

Tags: python, function, variables, default

I'm with something like this at the top of my code:

```
def fun_func(x=something):
    print(x+x)
```

And I got this:

```
NameError: name 'something' is not defined
```

Do I have to define my function necessarily after the default variable is declared? That only happens at the bottom of the code, so I think It looks kind of unaesthetic. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, but you can patch your function at the end of the file.

Comment: I guess that works too, but is it a good practice?

Comment: You have no choice. One workaround would be to make the default argument a mutable container, like a `list`, and change the contents of the list before the function is called. Mutable default arguments are normally not considered a good practice, but would be OK in these circumstances.

Comment: The function never uses `x`, what's the point of it? Did you mean to write `print(x + x)`?

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you ask for, but you can do something similar. Set the default value to some *other* sentinel value, then add a check in your function. `None` is often a good choice.

```
def fun_func(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = something
    print(x+x)

# lots of lines of code ...

something = 21
fun_func()
```

This way, the evaluation of `something` is deferred until `fun_func()` is actually called.

If `None` is actually a legitimate value of `x`, then you might prefer this slightly more convoluted method:

```
_sentinel = object()
def fun_func(x=_sentinel):
    if x is _sentinel:
        x = something
    print(x+x)
```

Comment: Some libraries write a custom type for their default sentinel, with a custom `__repr__`, so [generated docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) look like `f(x=<no value>)` instead of `f(x=<object object at 0xwhatever>)`.

Answer (score 0):

No (at least not without being overly "clever"); the problem is the line with "x=something", which is evaluated when the function declaration is reached (in other words, at "compile time"). The line that says "something+something" is not a problem as long as you define "something" before *calling* fun_func().